# convert Python list of lists to numpy identity matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to express in pure python what is being done by the np.kron function.

Let's say i have these lists:

```
v1 =  [1, 0, 0, 1]
v2 = [1, 0, 0, 1]
```

i would like to define a function that would create a list of lists by multiplying v1 by each element in v2. So these two lists would produce 4 lists:

```
[[1 * v1[0]],[0 * v1[1]],[0 * v1[2]],[1 * v1[3]]]
```

Currently, I can get the right lists from a list comprehension:

```
i = [[a*b for a in v1] for b in v2]

>>[[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]]
```

those lists are correct, but when i convert to np.array and reformat it, there are 1s in the quadrants rather than down the diagonal:

```
print(np.array(i).reshape(4,4))

[[1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1]]
```

if np.kron is passed v1, v2 after converting them to numpy arrays it would give:

```
i2 = np.kron((np.array(v1).reshape(2,2)),(np.array(v2).reshape(2,2)))

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

which is a beautiful 4 x 4 identity matrix; thats what im looking to express in pure python, rather than using np kron function.

Comment: `np.kron(v1, v2)` gives the exact same output as the list comprehension that you used above, and not the output that you claim it gives.

Comment: youre totally right. . i edited some things before i posted

Comment: Can you show the exact numbers you are expecting, not an expression that represents a 4x1 array?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't look right"? `np.array(i)` is already 4x4 because of how you defined it. Are you upset that it's not printing on one line?

Comment: basically, i want it to be formatted as an identity matrix. so each sublist would be converted to a 2x2 matrix , and 4 of matrices would form a 4x4 identity matrix.

Comment: @neutrino. Numpy works very differently from lists. I have no idea what you want based on the description you provided. Please post a concise description in the question including an example that shows the exact expected output.

Comment: the expected output is a matrix similar to the one output by np.kron. not trying to be difficult.

Comment: @neutrino. I wasn't either. I only just now parsed the last sentence. Really sorry about that.

Comment: What threw me off was the stuff about the 4x2 matrix. Is that a typo?

Comment: @neutrino. I've rewritten my answer form scratch. I think it's what you're looking for. Let me know.

Comment: I've flipped my vote, but you may consider rewriting or removing the extremely misleading initial portion of the question, where you talk about the wrong way to do it as if it was what you want. Conventionally, a for loop implementation in the question is taken as the template for what you want, since most numpy questions are about vectorizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the kron solution is by far the simplest (and you can always dump it into a list with [`.tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)), let's look at a pure python implementation.

There are two parts here: how to implement `kron`, and how to reshape a list. One way to do it is to make a grid that tells you which element to get from where at each location.

So the index into `v1` would look like:

```
0 1 0 1
2 3 2 3
0 1 0 1
2 3 2 3
```

The index into `v2` is something like

```
0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1
2 2 3 3
2 2 3 3
```

You can convert these into an expression in term of the row `r` and column `c`. The index into `v1` looks something like

```
i1 = 2 * (r % 2) + (c % 2)
```

For `v2`, you can write

```
i2 = 2 * (r // 2) + (c // 2)
```

If course it's the constant `2` that would change if you tried to shape the inputs or outputs differently.

Now you can just write a nested comprehension:

```
output = [[v1[2 * (r % 2) + (c % 2)] * v2[2 * (r // 2) + (c // 2)] for c in range(4)] for r in range(4)]
```

Comment: Nice one.  +1   Thanks for sharing.

Comment: this gives a matrix with 1s in the quadrants rather than down the diagonal; not sure what im missing.

Comment: @neutrino. You're missing a clear description of your problem. This is a solution to what you wrote in the question. Please fix the question to correspond with what's on your mind and I'll be happy to try to help.

Comment: @ScottBoston. Having figured out what OP wants, I completely rewrote the answer

Comment: thanks, i know kron is so much simpler, i was just trying to figure out how one would get a tensor product from a couple of lists without it. thanks again :  )

Comment: @neutrino. Glad we're finally on the same page. As with all tensor related things, it's always about the indices.